# Unreal Engine 4 + Qt5 integration

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, unreal-engine4

I'm a bit new in UE and i'm searching a way to make UE works with Qt for some of my projects ( like robotic simulation / sea simulation ), btw I don't want to use Slate.

I'm currently working on Windows with VS2015.

Is anyone knows where to start, I mean, where to start looking for flags or lib adds ?

Or a better solution should be to add Qt as a static library ? as [this](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Linking_Static_Libraries_Using_The_Build_System).

Comment: Can you be hmm more explicit maybe ?

Comment: You can't mix the two.

Comment: You're wrong, we can mix up these two.
See this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/49boow/question_ue_qt5_integration/) and [this one](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Linking_Static_Libraries_Using_The_Build_System)

Comment: Please post back with your progress; I would interested in seeing what you create.

Comment: Atm I'm testing slots communication for spawing Actors and changing on the fly the Base Color of objects.

Answer (score 0):

if you use **C++** for unreal & qt, this won't help you.

But if you use **Python** for unreal & qt :

You can add the [unreal_qt](https://github.com/hannesdelbeke/unreal_qt) module to your project. It works with unreal 5, and 4. The readme has step by step instructions on how to use it, with a python qt example.

### Quickstart

1. Add the unreal_qt folder in your python path. See [unreal docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProductionPipelines/ScriptingAndAutomation/Python/#pythonpathsintheunrealeditor)
2. Use the following code snippet to create `sample.py` and add it to unreal python path.

```py
# 1. SETUP - this step can automatically run on editor startup when added to your init_unreal.py
import unreal_qt
unreal_qt.setup()  

# 2. CREATE WIDGET - create your qt widget
# every widget you make after setup won't block the editor & have unreal styling
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
w = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
w.setLayout(layout)
layout.addWidget(QLabel("Hello World!"))

# 3. WRAP WIDGET - (optional) manage garbage collection, add darkbar, stay on top
unreal_qt.wrap(w)

# 4. SHOW WIDGET - if using stay on top this needs to run after the wrap stage
w.show()
```

3. import script in unreal with the Python terminal to run it.

```py
import sample
```